# How would I go about changing the contents of a div after the user searches?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have this form:

```
<form  method="post" action="index.php"  id="searchform"> 
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
        <input type="image" src="img/img1.png" alt="submit" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" /></a>
</form>
```

When the user searches for something I want to change this div:

```
<div class = "mainText">
    <h2>Today's Events: </h2>   
</div>
```

To say this:

```
<div class = "mainText">
    <h2>Results: </h2>   
</div>
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: Is it possible to run this code from within a php if statement?

Comment: `$('.mainText').html(...);` is one way to change the contents of a div ... What have you tried and where specifically are you getting stuck?

Comment: $('.mainText').empty().append('<h2>Results: </h2>')

Comment: The minute you submit the form, you will be redirected away from the current page, so no matter what you change the text to, no one will see it.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing Thanks very much! Got it to work with the code you gave me.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That isn't the case for this particular page but in general yeah. Thanks! Got it work anyways thanks to randominstanceOfLivingThing

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing Why bother with `.empty()`? Why not just use `.html()`?

Comment: @ScottMarkus Will also work with $('.mainText').html(...).

Answer (score -1):

jquery .text() seems a better fit, so you can just change the text of the tag.

```
         $(".mainText h2").text("Results:");
```

More on this here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp

Comment: The minute you submit the form, you will be redirected away from the current page, so no matter what you change the text to, no one will see it.

Answer (score -1):

The action in your form is the destination of where your form ends up.
If you are looking to control the dom elements you need something like javascript or jquery to control the front end of your application.
You could use jquery to simply listen for when your user has clicked the button or submitted the form and parse the results (in this case, just switching html text).  *Remove the the action destination otherwise the page will redirect to index.php

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('.mainText').html('<h2>Results: </h2>');
    return false;
});
```

Common usage is to put an ajax call in the submit function to retrieve some data from outside the page source.  Hopefully that puts you on track :)

Comment: The minute you submit the form, you will be redirected away from the current page, so no matter what you change the text to, no one will see it.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention removing the action from the form, see edit